# Why my string comparison returns an unexpected result?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I'm trying to create a form with an add button and some information text box. When I click the add button, all information given in text box should be read and show in list view and tree view. Here is my add button click event code.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(txtBYear.Text == "" ||
       txtGender.Text == "" || txtMSSV.Text == "" ||
       txtName.Text=="" || cBoxClasses.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Missing information!", "Error");
        return;
    }

    if (txtGender.Text !="Female" || txtGender.Text!="Male")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Male or Female only!", "Error");
        return;
    }

    var mssv = txtMSSV.Text;
    var name = txtName.Text;

    uint bYear;
    bool gender;

    var addr = txtAddress.Text;
    uint cl = (uint)cBoxClasses.SelectedValue;
    var clName = cBoxClasses.SelectedText;

    if (txtGender.Text == "Female")
        gender = true;
    else 
        gender = false;

    if (uint.TryParse(txtBYear.Text, out bYear))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Birth Year!", "Error");
        return;
    }

    var newStudent = new Student(cl, mssv, name, bYear, gender, addr);

    Classes x;

    if(classes.GetClassesById(cl, out x))
    {
        x.AttendingStudents.Add(newStudent);
    }
    else
    {
        var tmp = new Classes(cl, clName);
        classes.Add(tmp);
        tmp.AttendingStudents.Add(newStudent);
    }

    lViewMain.Update();
    tViewMain.Update();
}
```

I try type "Female" in txtGender text box and execute the button click but my comparison returns `true` which makes `Messagebox` pop up.

Why does my check `textGender.Text != "Female" ||txtGender.Text != "Male"` return that unexpected value?

Comment: *"Male or Female only!"* <-- This is a bug. Gender is not a binary. There are options other than male and female.

Comment: When you enter "Female", the text is not "Male", so your condition is true. Your condition can never be false!

Comment: There are quite some possible improvements to your code, by the way, starting from how you compare strings (look up `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` for instance) or understanding booleans: `bool gender; if (txtGender.Text == "Female")
            gender = true;
        else gender = false;` can be rewritten as `bool gender =  txtGender.Text == "Female"` although you should of course use an `enum` for things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does what you told it to do. Your condition `textGender.Text != "Female" ||txtGender.Text != "Male"` says "if the text is not 'Female' or is the text is not 'Male'.

Since it is not 'Male', it gets in the if block. What you need is the `&&` operator

Try using the following condition instead

`textGender.Text != "Female" && txtGender.Text != "Male"`

Answer (score 0):

The `||` operator means 'or' and returns true if either of the statements is true.

`textGender.Text != "Female"` returns `false`

`txtGender.Text != "Male"` returns `true`

That means that  `textGender.Text != "Female" || txtGender.Text!= "Male"` returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if (txtGender.Text !="Female" && txtGender.Text!="Male")
{
   MessageBox.Show("Male or Female only!", "Error");
   return;
}
```

Because, when text is not female and not male then you throw an error, if it is either of them, let it pass

Answer (score 0):

```
 textGender.Text != "Female" ||txtGender.Text != "Male"
```

Is true if `txtGender.Text` is `"Female"` since `txtGender.Text != "Male"` becomes true

What you want is

```
 !(textGender.Text == "Female" ||txtGender.Text == "Male")
```

Or

```
 textGender.Text != "Female" && txtGender.Text != "Male"
```